# If $X=A-F/3$, how to calculate $E(X)$, $Var(X)$ and $P(X≥5)$?

Tags: probability, self-study, distributions, variance, random-variable

### The exercise

An examination of questions with multiple answers, has 20 questions, and each question consists of 4 alternatives, one of which is correct.

The student's score is a random variable $ X $ given by $ X = A-\dfrac{F}{3} $,

where $A$ is the random variable "number of hits" and $F$ is the random variable "number of failures".

If a student answers at random all the questions:

- a) What is the distribution of variable $A$?
- b) What is the expectation and variance of $X$?
- c) What is the probability that the student will get at least $5$
  points in the exam?

### What I did

**a)** $A$~$B(20,1/4)$

*I assumed that $F$~$B(20,3/4)$, so that:*

- $E(A)=(20)*(1/4)=5$
- $E(F)=(20)*(3/4)=15$
- $Var(A)=(20)*(1/4)*(1-(1/4))=15/4$
- $Var(F)=(20)*(3/4)*(1-(3/4))=15/4$

**If part (a) is ok (maybe not). How can I resolve parts (b) and (c)?** Thank you very much.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "these types of exercises."  Apart from that, you ask *five* separate questions: the one in the title, questions (a), (b), and (c), and your "doubts."  Which one do you want us to address?

Comment: The problem is indeterminant as F and A are undefined. Bill Huber is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's less here than meets the eye; most of the question is based on the sleight of hand introduction of the variable $F$, which is just $A-20$ (These are NOT independent variables, just a trap for the unwary.)  Plug that into the definition of $X$, and calculate away!  Hint: $\Pr(X \geq 5) = \Pr(A > 8)$.

Comment: Surely you mean that F = 20-A rather than A-20